# Number of ideal classes of $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{2}\right]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, dedekind-domain

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{65})$, whose number ring is $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{2}\right]$.
I know that the number of ideal classes in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{2}\right]$ is $2$, and by Minkowski's bound I know that every ideal is equivalent to one with norm less or equal than $4$. Therefore, if $I\subset\mathcal{O}$ is an ideal, one of the following will happen:

- $||I||=2\Longrightarrow I\mid 2\mathcal{O}=P_1P_2$, with $P_1=(2,\sqrt{65})$ and $P_2=(2,\sqrt{65}+1)$
- $||I||=3\Longrightarrow I\mid 3\mathcal{O}$ which is prime
- $||I||=4\Longrightarrow I\mid 4\mathcal{O}=2\mathcal{O}2\mathcal{O}=P_1P_2P_1P_2$

Therefore, the $P_i$ cannot be principal ideals, whilst $P_i^2$ and $P_1P_2$ are principal (this is the only case where the number of ideal classes is $2$, and I have already proved that both $P_i^2$ and $P_1P_2$ are principal). Now I want to prove that neither $P_1$ or $P_2$ are principal ideals. This is where I am stuck.

If $P_i=(\alpha)$, with $\alpha=a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{2}$, then $2=||P_i||=||(\alpha)||=|N(\alpha)|$, where
$$N(\alpha)=a^2+ab-16b^2$$
So I have to prove that $a^2+ab-16b^2=\pm2$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Z}$. How can I do this? (I will face similar exercises in my final exam so I cannot use a code snippet or wolframalpha or anything like that.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know it is two but it is given to me as a hint. I have to prove it

Comment: @DietrichBurde the duplicate proves that $P_i^2$ is principal, not that $P_i$ isn't principal (which is what I need)

Comment: @DietrichBurde the comment by Lubin shows that there are principal ideals of norm $10$

Comment: Yes, you are right. This follows as in Conrad's computation on page $4$ [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/classgpex.pdf), i.e., that $P_i$ are not principal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde In the document you link they analize $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-65})$ which is nothing like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{65})$ because $-65\equiv 3 \mod 4$ and $65\equiv 1 \mod 4$, therefore their number rings are different. Can't you just reopen my question?

Comment: Conrad's article does several other examples, so I still think you can find the ideas there. What about a new question, directly asking about this ideal $P_2$, to show that it is not a principal ideal? Everything else in your post is answered at the duplicate and distracts from your essential question.